# Splicing load side of GFCI receptacle

Tags: gfci, load, splicing

I have a Junction box with incoming 120v coming into it.   I want to Install a GFCI recpetacle in this location.  From this same location I would like to splice the load side of the GFCI in order to protect planned receptacles which will be located to the left AND Right of this location. If I splice the load and carry load in 2 different directions, will this protect properly?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That's what pigtails are for. No problem at all.

- Incoming (from panel) wires -> LINE side of GFCI
- Outgoing wires - short pigtails (colors matching the outgoing wires, normally black & white) -> LOAD side of GFCI
- On the other end of each pigtail, wire nut the two matching wires to the other locations.

All grounds (both sides) are connected together.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you're connecting the wires at the load end, the GFCI doesn't care how it's connected.

You'll have to install a large enough box to accommodate 9 wires coming into it though.

According to this chart https://www.bhg.com/home-improvement/electrical/how-many-wires-in-an-electrical-box/ You're not going to be able to use a standard 3 x 2 box (even the 3 1/2 inch deep one), since your outlet counts as 2 wires, so you need a box that can accommodate 11 wires.

GFCIs themselves take up a lot of space, so be sure to size the box correctly, otherwise you'll never fit the number of wires in it safely.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and info.

Comment: Curently have a 4 inch square x 2 1/8" deep steel box with 3 1/2 inch thinwall conduits and plastic insulating bushings on the ends of each thinwall connector.thankyou for the link to calculate .  If need be I will change the box out before I terminate everything

Comment: 4 grounds together count as 1 wire.

Comment: will the 4 inch square 21/8" deep box be big enough? I could either change the box out or put an extension ring on it if its not.